# How to have different schemas within parquet partitions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have json files read into data frame. The json can have a struct field messages that is specific to name like below.

```
Json1
{
   "ts":"2020-05-17T00:00:03Z",
   "name":"foo",
   "messages":[
      {
         "a":1810,
         "b":"hello",
         "c":390
      }
   ]
}

Json2
{
   "ts":"2020-05-17T00:00:03Z",
   "name":"bar",
   "messages":[
      {
         "b":"my",
         "d":"world"
      }
   ]
}
```

when I read data from jsons into a Dataframe I get schema like below.

```
root
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- messages: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
```

This is fine. Now when I save to parquet file partitioned by name, how can I have different schemas in foo and bar partitions?

```
path/name=foo
root
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- messages: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)

path/name=bar
root
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- messages: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
```

I am fine if I get schema with all fields of foo and bar when I read data from root path. But when I read data from path/name=foo, I am expecting just foo schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`1. Partitioning & Storing as Parquet file:`**

If you save as **parquet** format then while reading `path/name=foo` [**`specify the schema`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878958/7632695) including **all** the **required fields**(a,b,c), Then spark only loads those fields.

- If we **`won't`** specify schema then **all fields**(a,b,c,d) are going to be included in the dataframe

**`EX:`**

```
schema=define structtype...schema
spark.read.schema(schema).parquet(path/name=foo).printSchema()
```

---

**`2.Partitioning & Storing as JSON/CSV file:`**

Then Spark **won't add b,d columns** into `path/name=foo` files, so when we read only the **name=foo** directory we won't get `b,d` columns included in the data.

**`EX:`**

```
spark.read.json(path/name=foo).printSchema()
spark.read.csv(path/name=foo).printSchema()
```

Comment: But if the data is saved with partitionBy clause I think the partitions will still contain the not required columns but with all null values.

Comment: @ShubhamJain, Thats true only for columnar formats, but if we store json then null will not get stored..!

Comment: What is best way to dynamically build one data frame/dataset to each name partition and then save them to path/name=<>? In the above example I have only 2 names but in my input I can have 100s of names.

Comment: to avoid null columns that contributed to partitioning use option `basePath` on read

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the schema before saving the dataframe in partitions, for this you have to filter partition records and then save them in respective folders

```
#this will select only not null columns which will drop col d from foo and a,c from bar
df = df.filter(f.col('name')='foo').select(*[c for c in df.columns if df.filter(f.col(c).isNotNull()).count() > 0])

#then save the df
df.write.json('path/name=foo')
```

Now every partition will be having different schema.